# Functor implementation for types with more than one type

Tags: scala, typeclass, scala-cats, higher-kinded-types, higher-order-types

let's say I have:

```
trait Get[F[_], A, B]{
  def get(a:A): F[B]
}
```

I want to be able to map over the result type B, ie I want to be able to do:

```
val getFoo: Get[IO, String, Foo] = ???
val foo2Bar: Foo => Bar = ???
val getBar: Get[IO, String, Bar] = getFoo.map(foo2Bar)
```

I understand that I should implement a `Functor` instance for `Get` but I am struggling as I don't know what type signature to use.

I tried the following:

- `implicit val functor:Functor[Get] = ???`
- `implicit val functor: Functor[Lambda[(F[_], K, A) => Get[F, K, A]]] = ???`

but they don't seem to be of the right type as I can't seem to use the functor syntax extension as illustrated at the top. What is the right way of expressing the type here? What would be the equivalent type be if I use the `kind-projector` plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
import cats.syntax.functor._

implicit def functor[F[_]: Functor, A]: Functor[Get[F, A, ?]] = new Functor[Get[F, A, ?]] {
  override def map[B, B1](fa: Get[F, A, B])(f: B => B1): Get[F, A, B1] = a => fa.get(a).map(f)
}
```

Comment: if I remove your map implementation and get IntelliJ to generate implementations for me with `???`, it gets them wrong. Is it a short-coming of Intellij or the compiler or the type projector plugin?

Comment: @Mathsnoob IntelliJ surely. How can code generation by IntelliJ be related to compiler or compiler plugin?

Comment: yeah I don't know why added compiler to the list :) my point is that if Intellij can understand what methods a signature needs for say `Functor[List]` then why can it not do it for the above. what's different in these cases? how are they different.

Comment: @Mathsnoob The difference is that we already have `A` in `implicit def functor[F[_]: Functor, A]...` IntelliJ just doesn't use fresh type variable. If you start with `implicit def functor[F[_]: Functor, A0]: Functor[Get[F, A0, ?]] = ...` everything will be ok.